# XML Request Generated From WSDL Always adding a namespace

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, ant, wsdl

I am having an issue where a request being generated from a WSDL is always appending a namespace to the element one step down from the Soap Body element. We are using Apache Ant and a wsimport command to generate the associated java files.

The recipient desires the request to be in the following format:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope
    xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <OTMSS>
            <username>username</username>
            <password>password</password>
            <OtherStuff>
                foo
            </OtherStuff>
        </OTMSS>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

But the WSDL they have provided:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="SS" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/SS_jws/SS/SS"
                  xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/"
                  xmlns:ns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm"
                  xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/SS_jws/SS/SS"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
>
    <wsdl:documentation>
        <abstractWSDL>http://customer:8001/soa-infra/services/default/SS!1.0/SS.wsdl</abstractWSDL>
    </wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:types>
      <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
          <xs:element name="OTMSS" type="OTMSSType"/>
          <xs:element name="OtherStuff" type="otherStuffList"/>
          <xs:complexType name="OTMSSType">
              <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="username" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="password" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element name="OtherStuff" type="otherStuffList"/>
              </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
          <xs:complexType name="otherStuffList">
              <xs:sequence>
                  foo
              </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
      </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="SSRequestMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="payload" element="OTMSS"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="SSResponseMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="payload" element="OTMSS"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="SS">
        <wsdl:operation name="process">
            <wsdl:input message="client:SSRequestMessage"/>
            <wsdl:output message="client:SSResponseMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="SSBinding" type="client:SS">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="process">
            <soap:operation soapAction="process" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="SS_client_ep">
        <wsdl:port name="SS_pt" binding="client:SSBinding">
            <soap:address location="https://customerEndpoint:9443/Company/services/SS_client_ep/"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
    <plnk:partnerLinkType name="SS">
        <plnk:role name="SSProvider">
            <plnk:portType name="client:SS"/>
        </plnk:role>
    </plnk:partnerLinkType>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Seems to always append a namespace to the OTMSS element as seen here:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope
    xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:OTMSS
            xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/SS_jws/SS/SS">
            <username>username</username>
            <password>password</password>
            <OtherStuff>
                foo
            </OtherStuff>
        </ns2:OTMSS>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

My question is what in the WSDL needs to change in order to remove this namespace altogether? When a request is generated via SoapUI, it looks like how the customer wants, but when generated via Ant it always seems to default that element's namespace.

In my troubleshooting process, I have been attempting to edit the wsdl and re-generate the sources that build the xml to correct this, but it seems like a default namespace is always being filled in. I removed every reference to the "client" prefix along with its associated namespace from the WSDL but then the OTMSS element in the request had a namespace that looked like 'ns2:OTMSS xmlns="FolderStructure/ThatHouses/TheJavaFiles/InReverse">'. Very odd.

Comment: As a side note, when the namespace is included they return a "oracle.fabric.common.FabricException: Unable to find operation: unknown"

Comment: I'm not sure it's the `xmlns:client` namespace that's causing the problem. Your elements are defined as being in that namespace by the `targetNamespace` attribute. Have you tried removing `targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/SS_jws/SS/SS"
`?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Yes I have tried removing all mention of the namespace, the one that is declared as client and the targetNamespace you mentioned. However, then the package gets added into the namespace.

I actually ended up solving this problem by using a handler/resolver to just edit the message directly before it is sent. Not ideal of course but gets the job done.

Comment: Fair enough and we'll done! :-)